# Can I change Button stroke color when my two EditText are not empty?

Tags: java, android

How can I change the stroke color of a `Button` when two `EditText` are not empty?

Code:

```
if (editText1.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0 && editText2.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
    btn.setBackgroundResources(R.drawable.change_stroke);
} else {
    btn.setBackgroundResources(R.drawable.change_normal);
}
```

Comment: what is problem using current code?

Comment: Not Effect.. On runtime.. now m to much tired

Comment: Are R.drawable.change_stroke and R.drawable.change_normal images or xml? If xml please provide the code.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
</shape> // change_stroke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement and register a `TextWatcher` for each `EditText`.

With some code:

```
    // lookup for Views
    final EditText e1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final EditText e2 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final Button btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);

    // TextWatcher definitions (to react on text changes)
    TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (e1.getText().length() > 0 && e2.getText().length() > 0) {
                btn.setBackgroundResources(R.drawable.change_stroke);
            } else {
                btn.setBackgroundResources(R.drawable.change_normal);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    }

    // text watcher registration to the 2 EditText
    e1.addTextChangedListener(tw);
    e2.addTextChangedListener(tw);
```

Comment: Once u write in some data in EditText , It will run perfectly.. But When u erase or remove data from EditText and make EditText Empty, At that case button stroke will not be changed... ??

Answer (score 0):

use text watcher . `onTextChanged` do your magic there.

```
private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private View view;

    private MyTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        //set the default button stroke color

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            //set the final button stroke color

        }
      }
  }
```

Define your colors using drawable file or in the resource file

Comment: can u more explain it..?? Please

Comment: so set a text watcher on the edit text that monitors key strokes...before you start typing set the button stroke color to your desired colors and after typing set to your final desired color. edited answer

Comment: Due to onTextChange... i can handle only one textview, But if i want two edittext are filled after that button stroke should be changed.. then What to do??? Help me

Comment: use the `if condition`  i.e view.getid ==R.id.editext1